# Can't access static resource using thymeleaf in specific end points

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have basic Spring Boot application with thymeleaf starter.(`2.0.1.RELEASE`)

This is project structure

[image]

As you can see I have html pages (`test,test-exchange`)
I have one controller to access these two pages:

[image]

`test.html and test-exchange.html` pages are absolutely the same

[image]

Here I have `tagManager.js` in the following dir

```
/resources/static/js/tagManager.js
```

In test-exhange.html I can't load this script, but in test.html I can(I mean in developer console I get 404 accessing script).

What is interesting , if I change endpoint to test-exchange.html  like this one

[image]

Script is loaded successfully.As I understand `thymeleaf` doesn't allow to have same string in controller to achieve page.
How to fix it???

Comment: A small note for improving your questions: please paste the code as code blocks instead of images. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Okey , I will do it in future ,any suggestion about this problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because of the relative mapping of your js files. The page under `xxx/test` is loaded and tries to load the js file from `xxx/js/tagManager.js`, but if you are at the url `xxx/test/something` it will try to load the js file from `xxx/test/js/tagManager.js`. Thus you will need the mapping from the root of your domain.

You can achieve this with `@{/js/tagManager.js}` instead of `js/tagManager.js`.

This would look like this:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/tagManager.js}"></script>
```

If anything is unclear feel free to ask

Comment: do you mean <script th:src="${'/js/tagManager.js'}"></script> this?

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak, yes

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak, but please note that it is with a `@` and no quotes inside of the curly brackets